# how is the sidebar sticking to the bottom of the page in this bootstrap template?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I don't really understand how they are making this sidebar stick to the bottom of the page in this bootstrap template.

http://getbootstrap.com/examples/dashboard/#

If you look at the .sidebar class CSS properties, there is this weird

```
position: fixed; top: 51px; bottom: 0px;
```

But really no rule about the height of the column, and since it should automatically adjust to the height of the content, I'm a bit lost here.

I made an attempt with this CodePen :

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ojQvjj

but really, the only way I found to make the sidebar stick to the bottom was to add a height property.

Thanks a lot for the answers, it will really help me make progress with CSS.

Comment: It's just the CSS you have. The combination of position fixed, a top value and a bottom value.. here is your updated pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VvVZbm

Comment: That's just weird, because of course I tried this CSS before asking, but when I added the bottom: 0 property, it dragged the div all the way down. That's weird behavior though

Answer (score 1):

If you make a container or element (`.sidebar`) with `position: fixed;` + `top: 0; bottom: 0;` That container will 'stick' to the top **and** bottom of the parent element (`body`).
When you use a 'fixed navbar' in bootstrap, you need to add a `margin-top > 50px` or, in this case,`top: 51px;` so the sidebar starts after the navbar and it's not hiding behind it.
At some point it will overflow, that's why they add, `overflow-y: hidden or scroll;`

To be clearer. If you remove those `.col-sm-3 .col-md-2` from that element, and give the `.sidebar` a `left: 0; right: 0;` it will take the whole viewport area.

Comment: thanks for the answer. What's weird is that I tried this set of property but it didn't work properly, see the comment I just posted at the top. Is this a css "hack" or is it a wanted behavior ? I mean, shouldn't there be a conflict between top:0 and bottom:0 that would cause inconsistencies between browsers ?

Comment: It's the wanted behavior (if i understand correctly).
You got to be careful when remaking bootstrap-like layouts as bootstrap classes work by inheriting properties from parent elements. That's why you have to follow some kind of nesting when using it. I'll check your codepen in a bit. (i'm on the phone)

Comment: Yes to my understanding when remaking bootstrap layouts I have to change at the most specific level as possible not to break the inherited properties on other elements. thanks for the help anyway

Answer (score 0):

Here if you see the code `col-md-2` in first div and `col-md-10` in second div and making first div as `position: fixed;` and when we make a div as position fixed it don't acquire any space in view port. and second div with `col-md-10` will acquire that place but it will be hidden behind top position of first div so we use `.col-md-offset-2` to move second div to `16.66 %` right direction and `top:0` and `bottom:0` for giving position to a fixed div.

and whatever you want is there: please check you this codepen:

http://codepen.io/Gkakar/pen/KdrzBJ